# I want to convert an excel file in R using bibliometrix

Tags: r, excel, excel-formula, rstudio

this is the error am experiencing

```
library(bibliometrix)
Md <- readFiles("C:/Users/Junior/Desktop/Mikoko.xls")
Cd <- convert2df(Md, dbsource = "isi", format = "bibtex")
```

Converting your isi collection into a bibliographic dataframe

> Error in seq.default(iP, iPs) : 'to' must be a finite number

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide more details, in particular the context, what you try to achieve, what yo did to achieve it and your previous attempts to solve your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://github.com/massimoaria/bibliometrix/issues/31 it says that it is related to having "UTF-8" as the default encoding in your R session.